# Where does dev_dbg writes log to?

Tags: linux-device-driver

In a device driver source in the Linux tree,  I saw `dev_dbg(...)` and `dev_err(...)`, where do I find the logged message?

One reference suggest to add `#define DEBUG` . The other [reference](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html) involves dynamic debug and debugfs, and I got lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dev_dbg()` expands to `dynamic_dev_dbg()`, `dev_printk()`, or no-op depending on the compilation flags.

```c
#if defined(CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG)
#define dev_dbg(dev, format, ...)                    \
do {                                                 \
    dynamic_dev_dbg(dev, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);     \
} while (0)
#elif defined(DEBUG)
#define dev_dbg(dev, format, arg...)                 \
    dev_printk(KERN_DEBUG, dev, format, ##arg)
#else
#define dev_dbg(dev, format, arg...)                     \
({                                                       \
    if (0)                                               \
            dev_printk(KERN_DEBUG, dev, format, ##arg);  \
})
#endif
```

`dynamic_dev_dbg()` and `dev_printk()` call `dev_printk_emit()` which calls `vprintk_emit()`.

This very same function is called in a normal mode when you just do a `printk()`. Just note here, that the rest functions like `dev_err()` will end up in the same function.

Thus, obviously, the buffer is all the same, i.e. kernel intrenal buffer.

The logged message at the end is printed to

1. Current console if kernel **loglevel** value (can be changed via kernel command line or via procfs) is high enough for certain message, here KERN_DEBUG.
2. Internal buffer which can be read by running `dmesg` command.

Note, data in 2 is kept as long as there still room in the buffer. Since it's limited and circular, newer data preempts old one.

**Additional information how to enable Dynamic Debug.**

First of all, be sure you have `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y` in the kernel configuration.

Assume we would like to enable all debug prints in the *built-in* module with name *8250*. To achieve that we simple add to the kernel command line the following `8250.dyndbg=+p`.

If the same driver is compiled as loadable module we may either add `options 8250 dyndbg` to the *modprobe* configuration or to the shell command line when do it manually, like `modprobe 8250 dyndbg`.

More details are described in the [Dynamic Debug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html) documentation.

The ["How certain debug prints are automatically enabled in linux kernel?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75060428/2511795) raises the question why some debug prints are automatically enabled and how `DEBUG` affects that when `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y`. The answer is lying in the *dynamic_debug.h* and since it's used during compilation the `_DPRINTK_FLAGS_DEFAULT` defines the certain message appearence.

```c
#if defined DEBUG
#define _DPRINTK_FLAGS_DEFAULT _DPRINTK_FLAGS_PRINT
#else
#define _DPRINTK_FLAGS_DEFAULT 0
#endif
```

Comment: I have CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y in my .config, but no output appears in dmesg output. Is there something else I need to do to get KERN_DEBUG output in dmesg?

Comment: @CarloWood, you need to activate it, for example by adding _dyndbg_ parameter to corresponding module.

Comment: Thanks. I am using "modprobe xhci_pci dyndbg==pmf" now.

Answer (score 2):

you can find `dev_err(...)` in kernel messages. As the name implies, `dev_err(...)` messages are error messages, so they will definitely be printed if the execution comes to that point. `dev_dbg(...)` are debug messages which are more generously used in the kernel driver code and they are not printed by default. So everything you have read about [dynamic_debugging](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.rst?h=v5.5.3) comes into play with `dev_dbg(...)`.

There are several pre-conditions to have dynamic debugging working, below 1. and 2. are general preconditions for dynamic debugging. 3. and later are for your particular driver/module/subsystem and can be .

1. Dynamic debugging support has to be in your kernel config `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y`. You may check if it is the case `zgrep DYNAMIC_DEBUG /proc/config.gz`
2. debugfs has to be mounted. You can check with `sudo mount | grep debugfs` and if not existing, you can mount with `sudo mount -t debugfs /sys/kernel/debug`
3. refer to [dynamic_debugging](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.rst?h=v5.5.3) and enable the particular file/function/line you are interested

Comment: I'm wondering what is your motivation to write an answer to this? Something I can amend in mine?

Comment: I just wanted to give a more explanatory type of answer for the people not so experienced with kernel. I guess OP either couldn't navigate or couldn't catch what macros are doing, so listing them once again here helps not much further.

Comment: Thank you, I have extended mine.