# How certain debug prints are automatically enabled in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel

I was exploring dynamic debug feature in linux kernel and [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html) gives enough details.

On my test setup, I have booted 5.16 mainline kernel on QEMU with below command:

```sh
qemu-system-aarch64 -smp 4 -m 2G -machine virt -cpu cortex-a57 -kernel uImage \
                    -netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \
                    -display none -serial mon:stdio \
                    -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=10.105.226.234:/home/naveen/nfsroot/rootfs-busybox-arm64,nolock,vers=4,tcp ip=10.105.226.235"
```

I am using Busybox as rootfs. I notice that certain debug prints are by default enabled e.g.

```sh
$ cat /proc/dynamic_debug/control | grep =p
drivers/scsi/libsas/sas_expander.c:2084 [libsas]sas_rediscover =p "ex %016llx phy%02d originated BROADCAST(CHANGE)\012"
drivers/scsi/libsas/sas_expander.c:2008 [libsas]sas_rediscover_dev =p "ex %016llx rediscovering phy%02d%s\012"
drivers/scsi/libsas/sas_expander.c:2048 [libsas]sas_rediscover_dev =p "ex %016llx phy%02d broadcast flutter%s\012"
drivers/scsi/libsas/sas_scsi_host.c:117 [libsas]sas_scsi_task_done =p "task done but aborted\012"
drivers/scsi/libsas/sas_scsi_host.c:122 [libsas]sas_scsi_task_done =p "task_done called with non existing SCSI cmnd!\012"
drivers/scsi/libsas/sas_scsi_host.c:193 [libsas]sas_queuecommand =p "lldd_execute_task returned: %d\012"
```

I have not passed any specific cmdline option to enable these. These are in-built into the kernel and not loaded as modules. Can someone please explain how above debug prints are enabled by default? In total, I have fair amount of logs enabled in mysterious way

```sh
$ cat /proc/dynamic_debug/control | grep =p | wc -l
37
$ cat /proc/dynamic_debug/control | grep =_ | wc -l
5513
```

I just wanted to know how these debug prints got enabled because I didn't enable them at least, so someone must be doing it.

Comment: First of all, drop yet another _Useless use of cat_, i.e. `grep /proc/... ` will work without `cat`.

Comment: Second, the answer to your question (in respect to your example) is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2-rc3/source/drivers/scsi/libsas/Makefile#L21.

Comment: As to why it is enabled by default, see [commit 15ba7806c316](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=15ba7806c316ce88d45db7d12d32380f53c01a06). "We add -DDEBUG for compilation so that we keep the debug messages by default, as before."

Comment: I am still confused. I have `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` which means we never reach the `DEBUG` check and end up in `dynamic_pr_debug()` : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/printk.h#L580

Comment: @0andriy , IanAbbott can you please clarify the follow up question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does dev\_dbg writes log to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950631/where-does-dev-dbg-writes-log-to)

Comment: @0andriy : Yes this answers the doubt. Thank you so much.